# Condition on the probabilities for the $J\times J$ matrix $[ \Pr(X=j \mid Y=k) ]$ to be invertible

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, probability-distributions, determinants, matrix-inverse

$\DeclareMathOperator\Pr{P}\newcommand\cPr[2]{\Pr(#1 \mid #2)}$I have a $J \times J$ matrix:
$$
M:= \begin{bmatrix} 
\cPr{X=1}{Y=1} & \cPr{X=2}{Y = 1} & \cdots & \cPr{X=J}{Y = 1} \\
\cPr{X=1}{Y=2} & \ddots & & \vdots \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
\cPr{X=1}{Y=J} &\cdots & \cdots & \cPr{X=J}{Y=J}\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are two discrete variables taking values in $\{1, \dotsc, J\}$, and $\cPr{X=j}{Y=k}$ are the conditional probabilities that $X=j$ knowing $Y=k$.

I want to find a "simple" condition (if it exists) on these conditional probabilities $\cPr x y$ under which $\det(M) \neq 0$.

**When $J=2$**, it is in fact very simple, we have:
$$\det(M) \neq 0 \iff \frac{\cPr{X=2}{Y=2}}{\cPr{X=1}{Y= 2}} \lessgtr \frac{\cPr{X=2}{Y=1}}{\cPr{X=1}{Y= 1}}.$$

Since the conditional probabilities sum to one for any $y$, we get that
$$\det(M) \neq 0 \iff \frac{\cPr{X=2}{Y=2}}{1-\cPr{X=2}{Y= 2}} \lessgtr \frac{\cPr{X=2}{Y=1}}{1-\cPr{X=2}{Y= 1}}.$$

And since the function $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1]$ where our probabilities lie, we simply get that
$$\det(M) \neq 0 \iff \cPr{X=2}{Y=2} \lessgtr \cPr{X=2}{Y=1}.$$

I'm trying to find a similar condition (but obviously more complex) under which it is true for the general case $J \times J$. I don't know if such a condition exists but I think it should exist, yet I've not been able to find it.

Comment: What is the difference between $\ne$ and $\lessgtr$ ... you used both.

Comment: Also $\operatorname{Pr}$ and $\operatorname P$.

Comment: No difference between $\lessgtr$ and $\neq$ in this case; Also P is Pr yes.

Comment: Equivalently: When is a stochastic matrix $p$ invertible? Or $p \cdot p^t$ invertible.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: There's no need for `\operatorname{Pr}`; you can just use `\Pr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the condition $\det M\ne0$ can be expressed as a certain non-independence condition, as follows.

For $i$ and $j$ in $[J]:=\{1,\dots,J\}$, let
\begin{equation*}
    p_{i|j}:=P(X=i|Y=j),
\end{equation*}
so that $M=[p_{i|j}]_{i,j\in[J]}$.

Suppose that $\det M=0$. Then for some real $c_1,\dots,c_J$ not all of which are $0$ and for all $i\in[J]$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{j\in[J]}c_j p_{i|j}=0. \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Summing both sides of (1) in $i\in[J]$ and noting that $\sum_{i\in[J]}p_{i|j}=1$ for each $j\in[J]$, we get $\sum_{j\in[J]}c_j=0$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{j\in A}c_j=-\sum_{j\in A^c}c_j=\frac12\sum_{j\in[J]}|c_j|>0, \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    A:=\{j\in[J]\colon c_j>0\},\quad A^c:=[J]\setminus A. 
\end{equation*}
For $j\in[J]$, let
\begin{equation*}
    p_j:=
    \frac{|c_j|}{\sum_{k\in A}|c_k|}.   
\end{equation*}
Let then $Y$ be a random variable (r.v.) with values in $[J]$ such that for all $j\in[J]$
\begin{equation*}
    P(Y=j)=p_j;
\end{equation*}
clearly, such a r.v. exists.
Then, in view of (2), we have $P(Y\in A)=P(Y\in A^c)=1/2$ and
(1) can be rewritten as $\sum_{j\in A}p_j p_{i|j}=\sum_{j\in A^c}p_j p_{i|j}$ and then as
\begin{equation*}
    P(X=i,Y\in A)=P(X=i,Y\in A^c)[=\tfrac12\,P(X=i)],
\end{equation*}
for each $i\in[J]$, which means that the r.v.'s $X$ and $1(Y\in A)$ are independent.

This reasoning is invertible, so that we get

> **Proposition 1:** Let $M=[p_{i|j}]_{i,j\in[J]}$ be the transpose of any stochastic matrix. Then
> $\det M=0$ if and only if there exist a subset $A$ of $[J]$ and a r.v. $Y$ with values in $[J]$ such that $P(Y\in A)=1/2$ and the r.v.'s $X$ and $1(Y\in A)$ are independent, where $X$ is any r.v. with values in $[J]$ such that $P(X=i|Y=j)=p_{i|j}$ for all $j\in[J]$ with $P(Y=j)\ne0$.

In the particular case when $J=2$, Proposition 1 reduces to this: $\det M=0\iff p_{1|1}=p_{1|2}\iff p_{2|1}=p_{2|2}$, as desired.

Comment: I'm quite confused with the $P(Y\in A) =1/2$. Maybe I misunderstood something but take the J=2 case, you do not need that $P(Y=1)=P(Y=2)=1/2$ for the determinant to be equal to zero. In fact $P(Y=1)$ can be anything. I understand the independence arguments though but I'm really unclear about the 1/2 (even though I see where it comes from in your development)

Comment: Now, I understand your $P(Y=j)$ has nothing to do with my "real" $P(Y=j)$ in the data, but is more a function of a linear combination of rows leading to a zero determinant. The $p_j$ actually sums to $1$ over $A$ but not over $J$ so they are not real probas but only weights. 
Then the idea is that you compare $P(X=i, Y\in A)$ to $P(X=i, Y\in A^c)$ and if they are equal for all $i$ then my determinant is zero. The condition $P(Y \in A) = 1/2$ is always satisfied by construction then no? So it has no real content/restriction power?

Comment: And I think your development implies that if the diagonal terms contains the highest value for every column (i.e. $Pr(X=i | Y=i) > Pr(X=i | Y=j)$ for all $j\neq i$) then I cannot find a combination like the one you require, and thus the matrix is invertible. 
It's only a sufficient condition but I think it is an interesting one and easy to interpret.

Comment: @G.Ander : Your conjecture about the diagonal domination does not hold in general. E.g., you have such domination for the stochastic matrix $M:=\dfrac1{544}\,\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 221 & 119 & 204 \\
 136 & 408 & 0 \\
 256 & 0 & 288 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, but $\det M=0$.

Comment: @G.Ander : However, the determinant will be nonzero (even for non-stochastic matrices) given a much stronger diagonal domination condition: "A strictly diagonally dominant matrix (or an irreducibly diagonally dominant matrix) is non-singular. This result is known as the Levy--Desplanques theorem." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Applications_and_properties)

Comment: @G.Ander : Since the question is about the matrix $[p_{i|j}]$ of the **conditional** probabilities, there is no "real" $Y$, even though you may have one for some other purposes, in other (even if closely related) contexts.

Comment: In the example, 256 > 221 in 1st column, doesnt fit the condition.
When J=3, I can prove it's true. Indeed, if $Pr(X=i|Y=i) > Pr(X=i|Y=j)$ for all $j \neq i$, then: 
Given your development, you have $c_1, c_2, c_3$ with at least two of them $\neq 0$, and which sum to $1$. Imagine $c_1 < 0, c_2 > 0, c_3 \geq 0$. Then we have $c_1 p_ {1|1} + c_2 p_{1|2} + c_3 p_{1|3} = 0 \iff c_1 p_{1|1} > - (c_2 p_{1|1} + c_3 p_{1|1}) \iff c_1 + c_2 + c_3 > 0$ which violates the condition that it sums to 0. Similarly, if you assume $c_2 < 0$, start with $p_{2|2}$...   
Now I need to check for J>3

Comment: Unfortunately it holds only for $J=3$ and does not extend to higher dimensions;

Comment: @G.Ander : I see. In my example in a comment, I forgot that $M$ is the transpose of a stochastic matrix.